# Oracle and Transaction naming

Tags: oracle, transactions, ado.net

I've been programing with SQL Server and C# for quite some time and I have some code that I need to change to work with Oracle:

```
SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)CreateDBConnection();
IDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(level, "name");
```

The problem is: if I use `OracleConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` there is no way to specify a name for my transaction. I know that the syntax in Oracle allows named transactions, but I don't seem to find a way to do it through .net code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the transaction name.
But it is possible to specify a name for the SAVEPOINT.

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection((string.Format("Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2}", DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD));
oracleConnection.Open();
OracleCommand oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand();
oracleConnection.BeginTransaction();
OracleTransaction oracleTransaction = oracleCommand.Transaction;
oracleTransaction.Save("name");
//...
oracleTransaction.Rollback("name");
```